# RadGrid - Exporting to CSV does not include template column

Tags: c#, export, telerik, radgrid

So I've got the following column defined in my radgrid:

```
                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="Payment.Customer.FirstName" DataType="System.String"
                    HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="Payment.Customer.FirstName" UniqueName="FirstName">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="hypFirstName" runat="server" Target="_blank" Text='<%# ((PaymentIssue)Container.DataItem).Payment.Customer.FirstName %>'
                            NavigateUrl='<%# string.Format("~/CustomerAdmin/Customer_View.aspx?customerId={0}", ((PaymentIssue)Container.DataItem).Payment.CustomerId) %>'></asp:HyperLink>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

Now, if I use the RadGrid MasterTableView.ExportToExcel() function; all is well.  However; if I try MasterTableView.ExportToCSV(), the column is blank.

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK; I figured this out.  Turns out I need to set the Text property on the GridDataItems before exporting.

Sample code below:

**Export Buttons Click Method**

```
protected void lnkExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var linkButton = (LinkButton)sender;
            switch (linkButton.CommandArgument)
            {
                case "Excel":
                    rgPaymentIssues.MasterTableView.ExportToExcel();
                    break;
                case "CSV":
                    PrepareRadGridForExport();
                    rgPaymentIssues.MasterTableView.ExportToCSV();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

**PrepareRadGridForExport snippet**

```
foreach (GridDataItem gi in rgPaymentIssues.MasterTableView.Items)
            {
                var hypFirstName = (HyperLink) gi.FindControl("hypFirstName");
                gi["FirstName"].Text = hypFirstName.Text;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting ExportOnlyData to 'False' solves this issue.
See the following link for the details.

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-csv-export.html

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone arrives here as I did, you could solve it another way, put another column with Readonly="true" so it doesn't appear in editing mode and the original column with Display="false" so it doesn't appear in view mode, then Export is all good, here's the extract:

```
<telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Email2" HeaderText="Email" UniqueName="Email2a" ReadOnly="true" Exportable="true" />
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="Email2" HeaderText="Email" UniqueName="Email2" Display="false" Exportable="false">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        ...
    </EditItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

Happy coding!